# Jupiter Notebook in vs code: python command not showing/ reading file from memory

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

my code is not showing any output after running specific commands for reading a file from storage location. I'm still a beginner so i'm little confused. Dropping my code here below

[image]

Comment: A Jupyter Notebook will only display the output when there is an output from the last line in a cell. Your first operation `file = open('D:\Personal\Notes\TLT.txt', mode = 'r')` does not have an output value, because it is an assignment. If you write and execute a cell with your variable `file`, it will output a file object. To exibit it's content, you should execute `file.read()` in a cell (before you close the file handler).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not reading the file your code, hence it does not show any output.

Try this

```
path = <path of you file>
file = open(path, mode="r")
file.read()
file.close()
```

You can also simplify it further

```
with open(path, mode="r") as file:
    file.read()
```

Comment: but if you don't save the function result it is a NOP operation

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the output of an executed cell, you should execute the variable you want to inspect in a different cell (or at the end of a cell). It wont work if it is inside the context manager (with clause).

```
[1] with open(path, mode="r") as file:
       content = file.read() 

[2] content
```